# Centered carousel without snapping in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a carousel-like view here using SingleChildScrollView, I want the item to snap in the middle of the screen when scrolling, one item at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally recommend using the `carousel_slider` package, which provides a lot of flexibility: You can use custom widgets and views, and create both horizontal and vertical carousels.

Pub link: https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider

Alternatively, if you'd want to create it yourself, I think you'd have to try around working with custom `ScrollController`s. Maybe take a look at the source code of the aforementioned package for some pointers.

Comment: It has not the function the item to snap in the middle of the screen when scrolling, one item at a time without snapping, It have value pageSnapping but this time it stops centering active slide